# Is it possible to migrate one Stack Exchange account to another?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, user-accounts

Is it possible to migrate a Stack Exchange to another? I have a private Google account and one for school business. Now, I'd like to migrate my personal one to my school account, so I can all use it for the same purpose. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ["Contact Us"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link in order to this since using this will send your request straight to a Stack Exchange employee. Be sure to fill in the correct information and to check your email often for any responses from Stack Exchange.